# SSIS 2012 Web Service Task - String is not of type Primitive Type

Tags: ssis, dts, ssis-2012

I am using SSIS 2012 and trying to call the following public web service:  https://www.asc.gov/wsvc/ASCQuerySvc.asmx?WSDL

I am able to successfully call the `GetQueryableFields()` method however when I try to call the `RunQuery()` method I get the following error:

```
[Web Service Task] Error: An error occurred with the following error message: "Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.WebServiceTask.WebserviceTaskException: Could not execute the Web method. The error is: The WebMethodInfo you have specified is incorrect. String is not of type Primitive Type..
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.WebServiceTask.WebMethodInvokerProxy.InvokeMethod(DTSWebMethodInfo methodInfo, String serviceName, Object connection)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.WebServiceTask.WebServiceTaskUtil.Invoke(DTSWebMethodInfo methodInfo, String serviceName, Object connection, VariableDispenser taskVariableDispenser)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.WebServiceTask.WebServiceTask.executeThread()".
```

I have scoured the web and the only thing I can find is that the Web Service task has issues with custom complex objects, no further explanation.  The only workaround I have found is to do a Script task instead, which I can do.  I'm only asking because it would be great if I could use the Web Service task over custom **C#** so that my BI guy doesn't have to wait on a developer before he can build these SSIS packages.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have the same problem. Figured it out after hours of troubleshooting.

When run the SSIS package to extract license data from ASC webservice, it failed with error message listed below:

*The WebMethodInfo you have specified is incorrect. String is not of type Primitive Type*

Because the datatype definition in the dtsx file is case sensitive.

To fix this, edit the dtsx file with notepad. Search for ***Datatype="String"***. There are three matches, only one with the upper case. Replace the upper case S in "String" with a lower case s --> "string". Save the dtsx file.

Comment: Thanks for the followup Huiyong.  Since it's been more than 3 years since I asked this question I no longer have a way to verify that this indeed the solution but I'll mark this as the answer anyways!